# Can a piece of code be dynamically placed on every webpage a user visit

Tags: javascript, browser

So we have a program that the user can use by copying text from a webpage they visit, alt+tabbing to the program, then pasting it as input. It would be more convenient for users to be able to do it directly in the site.

We were thinking of a panel that would be small and expandable, following them to each site they visit. Is this possible? Either a snippet of code that is auto pasted, or a JavaScript command called that would dynamically paste the code (is Scratchpad any help here, at least in FireFox).

We've never made a FF add-on, but it seems like if the dynamic panel idea falls through, an add-on would be the next best thing.

Basically, users should ideally be able to copy text, either enter a key combo or click a button, see the interface and paste in the text. Would either of these methods work?

Comment: If you're able to put a `<script src="app.js"></script>` element on every page, you're clear (= that would be a solution).

Comment: @Šime: I was tempted to post a joke answer along the lines of "become a huge ad company, make sure everyone includes your .js files, then modify them to produce the popups you want" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser add-on or a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/) could certainly do this.

You can also write a userscript and use a user script compiler (such as [this one](http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler)) to convert it to a "true" Addon.

Alternatively your application could act as a HTTP proxy and inject it dynamically, but I'd guess that this would probably be more complicated than the other two approaches.

Comment: I agree. A userscript/add-on is definitely the only best solution to this problem - à la Delicious Bookmarks for Firefox, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This site [Polyvore](http://www.polyvore.com/want_it_so_much/set?id=36758050) used to do something similar, although in the 2 mins hunting around I could not find it, but I have used it and I think the technique was used by Google and Digg for a while. From what I recal it involved iframes and a bookmark in your browser.

Basically you could download a small piece of code that would sit in your bookmarks bar and this would allow you to navigate to a fashion website click on the bookmark copy a picture and insert it back into Polyvore.